# Copy, Paste And Format

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I am currently working with this code to automate some tasks for senior staff members that are not very adept in Excel. Wondering if VBA is simply not a very quick code or if my code is clunky and slow.

For clarity, I would think with how simple this code is it could run in under a second or two. Maybe this is overzealous?

```
Sub Paste()

'---Paste Macro
'---2016-05-23

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell1 As Range
Dim StartCell2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set sht1 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet10")
Debug.Print sht1.Name
Set sht2 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet8")
Debug.Print sht2.Name
Set StartCell1 = Range("A2")
Set StartCell2 = Range("B2")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht1.Cells(StartCell1.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  LastRow2 = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Range And Copy into Final Formula Sheet
  sht1.Range(StartCell1, sht1.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 2)

'Convert Text in Column C of Final Formula Sheet to Numbers to Allow Advisor Code to Apply

 Set rng1 = Range(sht2.Cells(LastRow2, 3), sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + LastRow - 1, 3))
 With rng1
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
    End With

'Copy Advisor Function down to meet with new Pasted in Data
    With sht2
        Set rng2 = .Cells(LastRow2, 1)
        End With
    With rng2
        .Copy Destination:=Range(sht2.Cells(LastRow2, 1), sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + LastRow - 1, 1))
        End With

End Sub

'---This Function allows the worksheet name to change in the workbook as it allows the
    'user to set Worksheets to codename variables. By using this function the user can input a
    'codename for a worksheet and the function will call the worksheet name of the corresponding
    'codename, allowing the user to set worksheet variables to codenames without losing
    'functionality usually associated with such variables.
'---2016-05-23

Public Function GetWSFromCodeName(CodeName As String) As Worksheet

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If StrComp(WS.CodeName, CodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set GetWSFromCodeName = WS
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next WS

End Function
```

Comment: How quick is it? How quick do you want it to be? Also, what is `GetWSFromCodeName`?

Comment: Thanks @Zak! currently looking over your answer and seeing how it implements into my design. I feel it is promising, and will open me up to a new world of *fool proof*, though the world will always build a better fool. I'l update once I get everything in working order!

Comment: Also, things that often catch new people out: If you want to take the answers and incorporate them into your code and then get feedback on the \*new\* code, you need to do it in a follow-up question, detailed [here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Comment: For your next question I'd recommend you wait a while before accepting answers. @Zak's answer is excellent, but you may attract more answers by leaving it open.

Comment: It's just been pointed out to me that the previous link was broken. Apologies for that. If you want to drop by chat, this is the [correct link](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: Thanks @ Dan Pantry, I will keep that in mind. Very new to coding and stack exchange as a whole (as I'm sure most can tell) so any advice like this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 3 lowest-hanging VBA performance fruit are:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Just make sure to restore them at the end of your sub, and/or if your method encounters an error and stops, else your senior people won't be able to use Excel afterwards and will blame you for breaking it.

---

Used like so:

```
Sub/Function ()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

        < Code >

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic '/ Assuming it was set to automatic to begin with

End Sub/Function
```

And with some (very basic) error handling:

```
Sub/Function ()

    On Error Goto CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

        < Code >

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic '/ Assuming it was set to automatic to begin with

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub/Function

CleanFail:
    '/ Resets the Application settings, *then* raises the error
    On Error Goto 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic '/ Assuming it was set to automatic to begin with
    Err.Raise(Err.Number) '/ Or insert your own error handling here

End Sub/Function
```

Comment: Wow! Amazing how such a simple thing like stopping excel from making itself its own worst nightmare of constantly updating makes this code run infinitely faster! Fantastically simple answer to what I presume is also a fairly simple question. Many thanks to you and everyone else that stopped by!

Comment: I recommend you put your new code up for review. There's a **lot** of other things that you should get into the habit of doing.