# Copy, Paste and Format 2.0

Tags: performance, object-oriented, vba

**This is a follow up with revised code, see the original question and subsequent answer in the following link ([Copy, Paste And Format](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129187/copy-paste-and-format))**

This is a full version of all three "Macros" or subs within the workbook that I'm currently working with. I hope to use much of this as a reference in future automation to many other aspects of the work day that will make life for many of my work colleagues quicker and easier! Huge thanks to @Zak for a great answer, as he suggested this is the current revised code. I'm sure that there are still many things I could change and am still open to suggestions, though by and large this works for my purpose and is plenty quick now, running in under a seconds one after another as each "macro" is not required in all reports (this being an internal non-coding matter). I am currently mainly wondering of any bad habits glaringly obvious to the eye. As always all constructive criticism and critiques are welcome, though don't feel you have to fundamentally change my code as it is acceptable as of now for my use of it.

```
Sub SORT()

'/Sam Buford
' SORT Macro
' 2016-05-23

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

'/Macro recorded code follows

Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Select
    Range("D1").Activate
    Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,N:N,O:O,P:P,Q:Q,R:R,S:S").Select
    Range("S1").Activate
    Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    '/Resets the Application settings, *then* raises the error
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Err.Raise (Err.Number)

End Sub

Sub Paste()

'/Paste Macro
' 2016-05-23

On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell1 As Range
Dim StartCell2 As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Set sht1 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet10")
Debug.Print sht1.Name
Set sht2 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet8")
Debug.Print sht2.Name
Set StartCell1 = Range("A2")
Set StartCell2 = Range("B2")

'Find Last Row and Column
  LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row
  LastColumn = sht1.Cells(StartCell1.Row, sht1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  LastRow2 = sht2.Cells(sht2.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Range And Copy into Final Formula Sheet
  sht1.Range(StartCell1, sht1.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Copy Destination:=sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 2)

'Convert Text in Column C of Final Formula Sheet to Numbers to Allow Advisor Code to Apply

 Set rng1 = Range(sht2.Cells(LastRow2, 3), sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + LastRow - 1, 3))
 With rng1
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
    End With

'Copy Advisor Function down to meet with new Pasted in Data
    With sht2
        Set rng2 = .Cells(LastRow2, 1)
        End With
    With rng2
        .Copy Destination:=Range(sht2.Cells(LastRow2, 1), sht2.Cells(LastRow2 + LastRow - 1, 1))
        End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    '/Resets the Application settings, *then* raises the error
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Err.Raise (Err.Number)



End Sub

Public Sub ReplaceBlanksTeamID()

'/Fill Blank Team ID's Macro
'2016-05-23

 On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell1 As Range

Set sht1 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet10")
Debug.Print sht1.Name
Set sht2 = GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet8")
Debug.Print sht2.Name
Set StartCell1 = Range("A2")

'Find Last Row
  LastRow = sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, StartCell1.Column).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Range
sht1.Range(StartCell1, sht1.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Select
On Error Resume Next
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 2), sht1.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Select
With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[+1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    '/Resets the Application settings, *then* raises the error
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Err.Raise (Err.Number)


End Sub

    '/This Function allows the worksheet name to change in the workbook as it allows the
    'user to set Worksheets to codename variables. By using this function the user can input a
    'codename for a worksheet and the function will call the worksheet name of the corresponding
    'codename, allowing the user to set worksheet variables to codenames without losing
    'functionality usually associated with such variables.
    '2016-05-23

Public Function GetWSFromCodeName(CodeName As String) As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If StrComp(WS.CodeName, CodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set GetWSFromCodeName = WS
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next WS

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    '/Resets the Application settings, *then* raises the error
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Err.Raise (Err.Number)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks to all that helped with this! I have learned some better coding  practices, learned to rethink why i implemented certain things and if there is a better way, as well as learned some info on how Excel and Worksheets interact. This has greatly improved my code and made me very thankful that Code Review exists. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Raystafarian beat me to it, but it cannot be said too many times: **avoid `Select` and `Activate`**, keep that for macro-recorder generated code!

> ```
> Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Select
> Range("D1").Activate
> Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L").Select
> Range("L1").Activate
> Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,N:N,O:O,P:P,Q:Q,R:R,S:S").Select
> Range("S1").Activate
> Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
> ```

Most of this code is useless, you're making a selection, and then making another selection, and then making another selection... and then making another selection, and deleting it.

This would be equivalent:

```
Range("S1").Select
Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

And this would be a little better:

```
Range("S1").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

Except `Range` is implicitly referring to the active worksheet. Chances are, that's not what you want to do: you want to be referring to *a specific sheet*, e.g. `Sheet2`. Then *qualify`the`Range` function with it:

```
Sheet2.Range("S1").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

---

This is very troubling:

```
Public Function GetWSFromCodeName(CodeName As String) As Worksheet
```

The *code name* property of a worksheet is used to determine what identifier to use in code to refer to a global `Worksheet` object that refers to a specific worksheet. If you know the `CodeName` of a worksheet, *you already know what that worksheet is*.

```
GetWSFromCodeName("Sheet42")
```

Returns the same object as

```
Sheet42
```

VBA *already* creates an object named `Sheet42` for you to use; there's no need to create another object to refer to the same thing.

---

You're repeating this chunk quite often:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = {Boolean}
Application.EnableEvents = {Boolean}
Application.Calculation = {xlCalculation}
```

Why not extract it into its own parameterized function?

---

Your indentation is hard to follow.

> ```
> With rng1
>    .NumberFormat = "0"
>    .Value = .Value
>    End With
> ```

Try to line up `Foo...End Foo` statements:

```
With rng1
    .NumberFormat = "0"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

It makes it much easier to see what starts and ends where.

Sometimes indentation is simply inexistent:

> ```
> With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
> .FormulaR1C1 = "=R[+1]C"
> .Value = .Value
> End With
> ```

Some VBE add-ins offer an indenter tool to ensure consistent indentation throughout a project. I suggest you take a look at the latest [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com) and/or [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) - note/disclaimer: I'm heavily involved with Rubberduck.

Comment: Thanks @Mat's Mug! this is very useful info that will surely aid me in future eneavors of coding. I'm beginning to love SO and all its sister websites for its wonderful helpful community. I will look into all these changes time allowing and get back to this thread with my fixes and any issues I have. Thanks again to the SO community for  this wonderful first day experience!

Comment: in response to the first code block with many activates and selects, that was indeed macro generated, and i have made an edit to simply inform people that this is the case, currently that sub deletes 11 columns in a nastily formated raw data sheet

Comment: @SamBuford *cough* this is the CR community ;-)  ...if you run into specific issues, you should research first and ask on SO as a last resort; if you want further feedback I'd suggest making a new post, as changing the code in the question to incorporate feedback from answers is very much frowned upon on this site, and will be rolled back. I'd suggest you let a couple of days go by, to give more people a chance to point something out in *this* code, which has quite much to be said about. Cheers! =)

Comment: Thanks for your advice and ah i see your point there. CR is Stack exchange sister website just as SO, SO is not the main. Any who, I will leave this on and let the ideas build so as to hopefully learn some great practices as much of coding has been self taught except for a simple excel class taken last year at college.

Comment: The reason for the 'GetWSFromCN' function is outlined in the comment, but to be more specific it is my understanding that when using cell references to identify a dynamic range outlined by variables, 'CodeName.Cells(x,x)'  does not work in VBA, which is why I created a function to set a sht2 to the CN that returns the WS name which i can then use in a .Cells functin, in larger part being done to ensure the macro doesn't break from someone deciding to be clever and renaming one of the WS. If there is another way around this I'm happy to hear, but this was the solution I came up with on my own.

Comment: @SamBuford A worksheet's *CodeName* isn't its *Name*. Users can rename tabs/worksheets all they want and it won't change the `CodeName` of a worksheet. `Sheet42.Cells(x,y)` absolutely works in VBA (with IntelliSense even!), not sure what made you think it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm. Yes I do understand renaming WS doesn't rename the _CodeName_, this is why i built the function in the first place. What I didn't know was that you could use the cell references with _CodeNames_. I should then always use the _CodeNames_ yes? Never a need to use WS names as any changes to them within the Workboob which is easily changed by people unfamiliar with Excel would result in broken VBA Code?

Comment: The thing to realise is that, if your sheet has a \*codename\* of `sheet42` and a \*name\* of `"Some Sheet"`, then `Sheets("Some Sheet")` is the same object as  `sheet42`, which are both worksheet objects and so can be used like so: `sheet42.Range().NumberFormat....` etc.

Comment: @Sam also, using a refactoring tool (Rubberduck) to rename identifiers will (should) not break the code in any way.

Comment: @findwindow welcome to CR! :-D

Comment: =PPP so much slower here.

Answer (score 4):

The low hanging fruit this time is the use of `.select` and `.activate`.

Be sure to avoid things like `.Select` - it just slows the code down by needing to fiddle with the spreadsheet while doing everything else behind the scenes. There's a good question on StackOverflow addressing this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros .

This section right here -

```
Range("A:A,B:B,D:D").Select
Range("D1").Activate
Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L").Select
Range("L1").Activate
Range("A:A,B:B,D:D,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L,N:N,O:O,P:P,Q:Q,R:R,S:S").Select
Range("S1").Activate
Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

What does it *do*? It deletes cell `S1`. That's all. It can be consolidated into one line -

```
Range("S1").Delete shift:=xlToLeft
```

---

Now this chunk of code

```
'Select Range
sht1.Range(StartCell1, sht1.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Select
On Error Resume Next
sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 2), sht1.Cells(LastRow, 2)).Select
With Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[+1]C"
.Value = .Value
End With
```

You have `On Error Resume Next` but I don't see a `For` **and** you have an error handler. What's the goal here? To fill in blanks? You can use a loop and `IsEmpty` or `IsBlank` instead.

```
For Each c In sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(2, 2), sht1.Cells(LastRow, 2))
    If IsEmpty(c) Then 'do something
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks! I checked that article out in great detail during my learning of this and in a similar question I asked on the main SO site.  That is definitely something easy I can update and will ensure good practices moving forward.

Comment: That code simply sorts raw imported data from a very nastily formatted file and removes unnecessary columns, 11 columns to be exact that are not needed in the following worksheet. that was a recorded macro-a quick fix if you will- about 4 months ago that I made very quickly. Now that I have more time to dedicate to this, hopefully i can clean it up a bit. Atleast in practice that is what is occurring in my worksheet